# xterm don't steal focus

Tags: rhel, xterm

I'm running a series of applications that open xterm windows on a RHEL4.6 enviroment with mobaxterm serving as a xserver running on windows7. Every xterm window that starts steals the focus and I have to wait for all the applications to launch their xterm windows before I can do anything because whatever I'm typing just gets stolen by each successive xterm window. I have a ~/.Xdefaults file in my ~ account but its just got a font size in there. Is there any setting that anyone knows of I can use to make them run in the background say?

Answer (score 0):

You could start xterm initially iconified:

```
xterm -iconic
```

from the [manual page](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html):

> **`-iconic`**
>   This  option indicates that xterm should ask the window manager
>   to start it as an icon rather than as the normal  window.   The
>   corresponding resource name is **`iconic`**.

Comment: This is what i've got: /usr/bin/xterm -iconic -geom 110x24+25+25 -xrm XTerm*iconGeometry:+0+0, and its still stealing focus.

Comment: I'm missing some detail: running as an icon, the program does not acquire focus until it is uniconified.

Comment: what would cause it to un-iconify?

Comment: Either the user clicks on it (and using window manager operations) does this, or xterm can also respond to an escape sequence to change its state.